# STM32 Loopback not Properly reading value

Tags: c, stm32, uart, dma

I have an stm32g484 that I am using to read a DS2431: (https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/DS2431-1389219.pdf)

I'm using the USART1 peripheral in an open drain configuration with a 2.2K pullup. I'm having trouble reading the bit value's from the EEPROM. This made me go down a debugging loophole and I've found that the RX data is not able to sample fast enough. Which seems odd because the 10us pulldown the EEPROM perform's should be well within the BIT sampling time of the UART as I have it configured.

Investigating this further I found that I can't actually properly loopback the data from TX/RX which is most likely the crux of the issue.

I've checked the lines with a scope and a logic analyzer and the waveform's are all good.
[image]
I've disabled all other interrupt's in the system and still am unable to read properly.

Below is roughly the minimum reproducible example and the code i use to setup the UART and send/receive the data:

Uart set to 115200 8 n 1

```
volatile uint8_t ow_rb[2];
volatile uint8_t data_received;
volatile uint8_t ow_tb[2];
volatile uint8_t data_sent;

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *uart) {
  data_received += 1;
  HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(uart, ow_rb, 1);
}

void run_app() 
{
    static uint8_t z = 255;
    uint8_t dbg_buff[100];
    while(1)
    {
    uint8_t dbg_buff[100];
    z -= 1;
    ow_tb[0] = z;
    data_received = 0;

    // Cancel Interrupts set UART to 115200
    HAL_UART_Abort_IT(owuart);
    HAL_UART_DeInit(owuart);
    huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
    huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
    huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
    HAL_UART_Init(owuart);
    while (HAL_UART_GetState(owuart) != HAL_UART_STATE_READY) {}
    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(owuart, ow_rb, 1);
    sprintf(dbg_buff, "115200 %d %d\r\n", z, ow_rb[0]);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(usb, dbg_buff, strlen(dbg_buff), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

    // Cancel Interrupts set UART to 9600
    data_received = 0;
    HAL_UART_Abort_IT(owuart);
    HAL_UART_DeInit(owuart);
    huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
    huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
    huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
    HAL_UART_Init(owuart);
    while (HAL_UART_GetState(owuart) != HAL_UART_STATE_READY) {}
    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(owuart, ow_rb, 1);
    HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(owuart, ow_tb, 1);
    while (data_received == 0) {}
    sprintf(dbg_buff, "9600 %d %d\r\n", z, ow_rb[0]);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(usb, dbg_buff, strlen(dbg_buff), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    HAL_Delay(10);
    }
}
```

Doing this i receive data:

```
9600 98 96
115200 97 96
9600 97 65
115200 96 65
9600 96 64
115200 95 64
9600 95 95
115200 94 95
9600 94 92
115200 93 92
9600 93 93
115200 92 93
9600 92 88
115200 91 88
9600 91 91
115200 90 91
9600 90 88
115200 89 88
9600 89 81
115200 88 81
9600 88 80
115200 87 80
9600 87 87
115200 86 87
9600 86 84
115200 85 84
9600 85 85
115200 84 85
9600 84 80
115200 83 80
9600 83 67
115200 82 67
9600 82 80
115200 81 80
9600 81 65
115200 80 65
9600 80 64
115200 79 64
9600 79 15
115200 78 15
9600 78 12
115200 77 12
9600 77 13
115200 76 13
9600 76 8
115200 75 8
9600 75 11
115200 74 11
9600 74 8
115200 73 8
9600 73 65
115200 72 65
9600 72 64
115200 71 64
9600 71 7
115200 70 7
9600 70 4
115200 69 4
9600 69 5
115200 68 5
9600 68 64
115200 67 64
9600 67 3
115200 66 3
9600 66 0
115200 65 0
9600 65 1
115200 64 1
9600 64 0
115200 63 0
...
63 (Always stops at 63)
```

So loopback itself is not working.

RX is connected to TX via a 0 Ohm shunt and waveform's look clean.

Is this a timing issue/dma issue/open drain usage issue/configuration issue?

Setup Code looks as follows:

```
#include "main.h"

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim1;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim3;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim4;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart5;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_uart5_rx;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_uart5_tx;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart1_rx;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart1_tx;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_UART5_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM4_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void);
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_UART5_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  MX_TIM4_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim1);
  while (1)
  {
    run_app();
  }
}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = RCC_PLLM_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{
  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 96;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim1, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger2 = TIM_TRGO2_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 3;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 48000;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_TIM4_Init(void)
{
  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  htim4.Instance = TIM4;
  htim4.Init.Prescaler = 4;
  htim4.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim4.Init.Period = 46000;
  htim4.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim4.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim4, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim4, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_UART5_Init(void)
{
  huart5.Instance = UART5;
  huart5.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart5.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart5.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart5.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart5.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart5.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart5.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart5.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart5.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart5.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&huart5, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&huart5, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&huart5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&huart1, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&huart1, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{
  __HAL_RCC_DMAMUX1_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 1, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel2_IRQn, 1, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel2_IRQn);
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn, 1, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn);
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel4_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel4_IRQn);

}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
}

void Error_Handler(void)
{
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
```

The method used for setting baud rate:

```
void uart_set_baud(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint32_t baud_rate) {
  if (huart->Init.BaudRate != baud_rate) {
    HAL_UART_Abort_IT(huart);
    HAL_UART_DeInit(huart);
    huart->Init.BaudRate = baud_rate;
    huart->Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart->Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart->Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart->Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart->Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart->Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    huart->Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
    huart->AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
    HAL_UART_Init(huart);
    while (HAL_UART_GetState(huart) != HAL_UART_STATE_READY) {
    }
    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(huart, ow_rb, 1);
  } else {
    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(huart, ow_rb, 1);
  }
}


When the application stops I get an overrun error.
```

Comment: I would insert code to toggle one or two extra port bits to show what code is currently executing. Add these to your scope/LA measures and check that you are in sync with the transmissions. You might want to [edit] your question and **add** the results. Loop back needs to work before you proceed with your actual project.

Comment: Is there any portion of the code that you would recommend looking at for toggling the bit's the callbacks available are TX complete RX Complete and their half complete counter part's. The only time loopback doesn't work is when i switch the baud rates so I'm guessing this would need to be a timing related issue associated with the baudrate's and their dma channels.

Comment: There is a lot of code missing here.  The most obvious thing is that HAL_UART_Receive_DMA is a non-blocking API that starts the DMA receive and causes you to get an interrupt callback when it is complete.  I guess you may be printing the contents of the buffer before the DMA has filled it.  How about editing the question to show the setup of the DMA peripheral and the interrupt functions.  Also you call `uart_set_baud`, where is that defined?

Comment: I've added the setup code. I forgot to edit out the *uart_set_baud* call when I was pasting it over. The UART receive is non blocking and that's why I wait for the data_received variable to be incremented in the RxCplt callback until it print's

Comment: Yes, correct. Mark important places, especially when you change the baud rate. Additionally, you can mark start end end of sending and receiving. I suspect that you change the baud rate in the middle of the byte. -- Hint: I commonly use one port bit and let the program output different number of short pulses. But any other pattern will work, too.